# Passing information by a form to 3 separate components using MongoDB and React

Tags: reactjs

I am building a website for a comic shop and I am struggling to pass information to 3 different components (**back issues, new comics, trades**) via a form. Currently I can post data to back issues, however I would like to pass similar information from a form to each of the components depending on whether it is a **back issues**, **new comics** or a **trade**.

I have tried adding product actions for new comics and trades but still don't understand how these can be recognised in a form

**What do I need to do so that the user can select on the form one of these options and the data is then correctly posted to the correct component?**

1. My production action for this thus far is:

```
export function getProductsToShop(skip, limit, filters  = []){
    const data ={limit, skip, filters}
    const request = axios.post(`${PRODUCT_SERVER}/Shop/back_issues`, data)
        .then(response => {
                return {
                size: response.data.size,
                articles: response.data.articles
            }
        });

    return {
        type: GET_PRODUCTS_TO_SHOP,
        payload: request
    }

}

export function getProductsToShop(skip, limit, filters  = []){
    const data ={limit, skip, filters}
    const request = axios.post(`${PRODUCT_SERVER}/Shop/new_comics`, data)
        .then(response => {
                return {
                size: response.data.size,
                articles: response.data.articles
            }
        });

    return {
        type: GET_PRODUCTS_TO_SHOP,
        payload: request
    }

}


export function getProductsToShop(skip, limit, filters  = []){
    const data ={limit, skip, filters}
    const request = axios.post(`${PRODUCT_SERVER}/Shop/trades`, data)
        .then(response => {
                return {
                size: response.data.size,
                articles: response.data.articles
            }
        });

    return {
        type: GET_PRODUCTS_TO_SHOP,
        payload: request
    }

}
```

2. My production action for this thus far is:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import UserLayout from '../../../hoc/user';
import FormField from '../../utils/Form/formfield';
import { update, generateData, isFormValid, populateOptionFields, resetFields } from '../../utils/Form/formActions';
import FileUpload from '../../utils/Form/fileupload';

import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import {getCharacters, getPublishers, addProduct, clearProduct } from '../../../actions/products_actions'

class AddProduct extends Component {

    state={
        formError:false,
        formSuccess:false,
        formdata:{
            name: {
                element: 'input',
                value: '',
                config:{
                    label: 'Product title',
                    name: 'name_input',
                    type: 'text',
                    placeholder: 'Enter title'
                },
                validation:{
                    required: true
                },
                valid: false,
                touched: false,
                validationMessage:'',
                showlabel: true
            },
            description: {
                element: 'textarea',
                value: '',
                config:{
                    label: 'Product description',
                    name: 'description_input',
                    type: 'text',
                    placeholder: 'Enter your description'
                },
                validation:{
                    required: true
                },
                valid: false,
                touched: false,
                validationMessage:'',
                showlabel: true
            },
            price: {
                element: 'input',
                value: '',
                config:{
                    label: 'Product price',
                    name: 'price_input',
                    type: 'number',
                    placeholder: 'Enter your price'
                },
                validation:{
                    required: true
                },
                valid: false,
                touched: false,
                validationMessage:'',
                showlabel: true
            },
            character: {
                element: 'select',
                value: '',
                config:{
                    label: 'Product Character',
                    name: 'character_input',
                    options:[]
                },
                validation:{
                    required: true
                },
                valid: false,
                touched: false,
                validationMessage:'',
                showlabel: true
            },
            issue: {
                element: 'input',
                value: '',
                config:{
                    label: 'Issue number',
                    name: 'issue_input',
                    type: 'number',
                    placeholder: 'Enter issue number'
                },
                validation:{
                    required: true
                },
                valid: false,
                touched: false,
                validationMessage:'',
                showlabel: true

            },
            shipping: {
                element: 'select',
                value: '',
                config:{
                    label: 'Shipping',
                    name: 'shipping_input',
                    options:[
                        {key:true,value:'Yes'},
                        {key:false,value:'No'},
                    ]
                },
                validation:{
                    required: true
                },
                valid: false,
                touched: false,
                validationMessage:'',
                showlabel: true
            },
            available: {
                element: 'select',
                value: '',
                config:{
                    label: 'Available, in stock',
                    name: 'available_input',
                    options:[
                        {key:true,value:'Yes'},
                        {key:false,value:'No'},
                    ]
                },
                validation:{
                    required: true
                },
                valid: false,
                touched: false,
                validationMessage:'',
                showlabel: true
            },
            publisher: {
                element: 'select',
                value: '',
                config:{
                    label: 'Publisher',
                    name: 'publisher_input',
                    options:[]

                },
                validation:{
                    required: true
                },
                valid: false,
                touched: false,
                validationMessage:'',
                showlabel: true
            },
            publish: {
                element: 'select',
                value: '',
                config:{
                    label: 'Publish',
                    name: 'publish_input',
                    options:[
                        {key:true,value:'Public'},
                        {key:false,value:'Hidden'},
                    ]
                },
                validation:{
                    required: true
                },
                valid: false,
                touched: false,
                validationMessage:'',
                showlabel: true
            },

            images:{
                value:[],
                validation:{
                    required: false
                },
                valid: true,
                touched: false,
                validationMessage:'',
                showlabel: false
            }
        }
    }

    updateFields = (newFormData) => {
        this.setState({
            formdata: newFormData
        })
    }



    updateForm = (element) => {
        const newFormdata = update(element,this.state.formdata,'products');
        this.setState({
            formError: false,
            formdata: newFormdata
        })
    }

    resetFieldHandler = () => {
        const newFormData = resetFields(this.state.formdata,'products');

        this.setState({
            formdata: newFormData,
            formSuccess:true
        });
        setTimeout(()=>{
            this.setState({
                formSuccess: false
            },()=>{
                this.props.dispatch(clearProduct())
            })
        },3000)
    }


    submitForm= (event) =>{
        event.preventDefault();

        var dataToSubmit = generateData(this.state.formdata,'products');
        var formIsValid = isFormValid(this.state.formdata,'products')

        if(formIsValid){
            this.props.dispatch(addProduct(dataToSubmit)).then(()=>{
                if( this.props.products.addProduct.success){
                    this.resetFieldHandler();
                }else{
                    this.setState({formError: true})
                }
            })
        } else {
            this.setState({
                formError: true
            })
        }
    }


    componentDidMount(){
        const formdata =  this.state.formdata;

        this.props.dispatch(getCharacters()).then( response => {
            const newFormData = populateOptionFields(formdata,this.props.products.characters, 'character');            
            this.updateFields(newFormData)


        })

        this.props.dispatch(getPublishers()).then( response => {
            const newFormData = populateOptionFields(formdata,this.props.products.publishers, 'publisher');            
            this.updateFields(newFormData)


        })
    }

    imagesHandler = (images) => {
        const newFormData = {
            ...this.state.formdata
        }
        newFormData['images'].value = images;
        newFormData['images'].valid = true;

        this.setState({
            formdata:  newFormData
        })
    }




    render() {
        return (
            <UserLayout>
               <div>
                   <h1>Add product</h1>

                   <form onSubmit={(event)=> this.submitForm(event)}>

                   <FileUpload
                            imagesHandler={(images)=> this.imagesHandler(images)}
                            reset={this.state.formSuccess}
                        />

                   <FormField
                       id={'name'}
                       formdata={this.state.formdata.name}
                       change={(element)=> this.updateForm(element)}
                     />


                    <FormField
                       id={'description'}
                       formdata={this.state.formdata.description}
                       change={(element)=> this.updateForm(element)}
                     />

                     <FormField
                       id={'price'}
                       formdata={this.state.formdata.price}
                       change={(element)=> this.updateForm(element)}
                     />

                     <div className="form_devider"></div>

                     <FormField
                       id={'character'}
                       formdata={this.state.formdata.character}
                       change={(element)=> this.updateForm(element)}
                     />

                    <FormField
                       id={'issue'}
                       formdata={this.state.formdata.issue}
                       change={(element)=> this.updateForm(element)}
                     />

                    <FormField
                       id={'shipping'}
                       formdata={this.state.formdata.shipping}
                       change={(element)=> this.updateForm(element)}
                     />


                    <FormField
                       id={'available'}
                       formdata={this.state.formdata.available}
                       change={(element)=> this.updateForm(element)}
                     />



                    <div className="form_devider"></div>

                    <FormField
                       id={'publisher'}
                       formdata={this.state.formdata.publisher}
                       change={(element)=> this.updateForm(element)}
                     />



                    <FormField
                       id={'publish'}
                       formdata={this.state.formdata.publish}
                       change={(element)=> this.updateForm(element)}
                     /> 

                    {this.state.formSuccess ?
                        <div className="form_success">
                                Success
                            </div>
                        :null}

                        {this.state.formError ?
                            <div className="error_label">
                                Nope
                            </div>
                            : null}
                        <button onClick={(event) => this.submitForm(event)}>
                            Add product
                        </button>

                   </form>
               </div>


            </UserLayout>

        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        products: state.products
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(AddProduct);
```

Comment: Ok.  What is your question?

Comment: My form currently sends to one component but I need to have the option of sending it to 2 other components. The information being sent remains the same however I need to have the option of sending it to different places. How do I do this?

Comment: So... put that in your post

Comment: I just have, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: There is still no question in your post.  I'm trying to help you get it reopened so you can get an answer.

Comment: Submitting info by form to different components

My form currently sends to one component but I need to have the option of sending it to 2 other components. The information being sent remains the same however I need to have the option of sending it to different places. How do I pass information on a form to different components?

Comment: Tim, notice how there's not a single question mark in your whole post? That's a sign.  This question was closed (not by me) because there's no question in your post and nobody understands what you want.  If you hope to get it reopened and get some help, you're going to need to edit the post and put in more information. Specifically, what exactly you are trying to accomplish, WHAT YOU'VE TRIED, and the problem you're having with what you've tried. What information do you want to pass, what components do you want to pass it to, how do you decide which component gets what data?

Comment: Hi Kevin, thank you for helping, Ive never posted to Stack before so having these pointers really helps! Will rework my post so it is more clear and precise. Stay safe and thanks again.